# Codeigniter recursive function not returning value

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, php-5.5

I have issues with *codeigniter* recursive function which returns blank value. below is my function.

```
function recursive_data($url){

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $instaArr = (array) json_decode($output);

        // print_r($instaArr); // print value here

        if( $instaArr['pagination'] == "" ) { 
             return $instaArr['data'];            
        } else { 
            return $this->recursive_data($instaArr['pagination']->next_url); 
        }

    }
```

I am calling this above function in another function like this

```
    $return_data = $this->recursive_data($url);
```

It is returning blank value. while it is printing the value in commented code `print_r($instaArr)`

Comment: Try ths `return $instaArr['pagination']->next_url; ` No need call function on return type

Comment: But it want work i need all the data and not url in  return.

Comment: just use `return $instaArr`;

Answer (score 0):

please use it as bellow.

```
    function recursive_data($url){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $instaArr = json_decode($output,true);

    // print_r($instaArr); // print value here

    if( $instaArr['pagination'] == "" ) { 
         return $instaArr['data'];            
    } else { 
        return $this->recursive_data($instaArr['pagination']->next_url); 
    }

    }
```

Comment: same thing not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
function recursive_data($url)
{
    $objCurlData = new stdClass();

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $instaArr = (array) json_decode($output);

    // print_r($instaArr); // print value here

    if( $instaArr['pagination'] == "" ) { 
        $objCurlData->data = $instaArr['data'];
    } else { 
        $objCurlData->objChild = $this->recursive_data($instaArr['pagination']->next_url); 
    }

    return $objCurlData;

}
```